# JavaFx Scenebuilder.exe won't start and it looks like the included JVM won't run. How can I fix it?

Tags: javafx, jvm, scenebuilder, gluon, jvm-crash

Scenebuilder.exe will not start on my new PC either from IntelliJ, Windows explorer, or command line. It gives no errors and terminates instantly.  On a hunch I tried running the included JVM in 
C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin

java --version

I get the log below and it shows an access exception that looks like a bug in the underlying JVM itself, not in the execution of the SceneBuilder code.  I've been running JDK 11 on this AMD Ryzen just fine, and there are no DLLs sneaking in that do not belong there.  I need help, thanks!

```
C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin>java --version
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff8e3bf8f29, pid=12296, tid=11532
#
# JRE version:  (11.0.1+13) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode, aot, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x1e8f29]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\\hs_err_pid12296.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin>type C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\\hs_err_pid12296.log
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff8e3bf8f29, pid=12296, tid=11532
#
# JRE version:  (11.0.1+13) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode, aot, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x1e8f29]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line:

Host: AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor            , 12 cores, 15G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 18362 (10.0.18362.778)
Time: Sat Apr 25 09:02:07 2020 Eastern Daylight Time elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000002312e8c6000):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=11532, stack(0x0000005029100000,0x0000005029200000)]

Stack: [0x0000005029100000,0x0000005029200000],  sp=0x00000050291feee0,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e8f29]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e73d3]
V  [jvm.dll+0x37524b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x7394a9]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3e467d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3e6951]
C  [java.exe+0x3603]
C  [java.exe+0x178dc]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x17bd4]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6ce51]


siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000000000000


Registers:
RAX=0x0000a780aacf8fcc, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000006
RSP=0x00000050291feee0, RBP=0x0000000000000000, RSI=0x000002312e8c6000, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x0000000000000006, R9 =0x0000000000000006, R10=0x0000000000000006, R11=0x00000050291fe750
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00007ff8e3ff6d90, R14=0x000002312c602d98, R15=0x00000050291ff938
RIP=0x00007ff8e3bf8f29, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010256

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000050291feee0)
0x00000050291feee0:   000002312c60db10 00007ff94e71c6c0
0x00000050291feef0:   00000050291ff938 000002312c602d98
0x00000050291fef00:   0000000000000000 0000000000000400
0x00000050291fef10:   00006181910f784b 00007ff8e3ff6d90
0x00000050291fef20:   0000000000000000 00000050291ff938
0x00000050291fef30:   000002312c602d98 00007ff8e3ff6d90
0x00000050291fef40:   0000000000000000 00007ff92e470000
0x00000050291fef50:   00007ff8e4282558 0000000000000000
0x00000050291fef60:   00007ff8e3bf7277 00007ff94e6d1b1c
0x00000050291fef70:   0000000000000000 00007ff8e40745dd
0x00000050291fef80:   0000a780aacf8fcc 000002312c602d98
0x00000050291fef90:   00007ff800000000 00007ff8e3ff6d90
0x00000050291fefa0:   000002312e8c6000 00000050291ff0c0
0x00000050291fefb0:   0000000000000000 00007ff8e3bf73d3
0x00000050291fefc0:   00007ff92e450000 00007ff92e47d088
0x00000050291fefd0:   00000050291ff0c0 000002312e8c6000

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ff8e3bf8f29)
0x00007ff8e3bf8f09:   b8 00 00 00 48 8b 05 bc 40 85 00 48 33 c4 48 89
0x00007ff8e3bf8f19:   84 24 a0 00 00 00 48 8b e9 48 83 cb ff 48 ff c3
0x00007ff8e3bf8f29:   80 3c 0b 00 75 f7 33 f6 c6 44 24 30 01 40 38 35
0x00007ff8e3bf8f39:   c2 62 88 00 74 17 40 38 35 a3 c9 87 00 75 0e 33



---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x000002312c602d50, length=0, elements={
}

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

[error occurred during error reporting (printing all threads), id 0xc0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff8e414e1fd]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None


[error occurred during error reporting (printing compressed oops mode), id 0xc0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff8e4163b67]

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (0 events):
No events


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6af5a0000 - 0x00007ff6af5e7000         C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin\java.exe
0x00007ff9512e0000 - 0x00007ff9514d0000         C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ff950230000 - 0x00007ff9502e2000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ff94e6c0000 - 0x00007ff94e963000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ff94fb00000 - 0x00007ff94fba3000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ff9502f0000 - 0x00007ff95038e000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ff951200000 - 0x00007ff951297000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ff94f9e0000 - 0x00007ff94fb00000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ff94f390000 - 0x00007ff94f524000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ff94f2e0000 - 0x00007ff94f301000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ff94f530000 - 0x00007ff94f556000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ff94e520000 - 0x00007ff94e6b4000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ff94f240000 - 0x00007ff94f2de000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ff94e270000 - 0x00007ff94e36a000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ff942260000 - 0x00007ff9424e5000         C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.18362.778_none_e6c6b761130d4fb8\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ff947e60000 - 0x00007ff947e6a000         C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ff94f640000 - 0x00007ff94f976000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ff94e370000 - 0x00007ff94e3f0000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ff950df0000 - 0x00007ff950e1e000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ff94aa90000 - 0x00007ff94aaa6000         C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin\vcruntime140.dll
0x00007ff932a30000 - 0x00007ff932ada000         C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin\msvcp140.dll
0x00007ff8e3a10000 - 0x00007ff8e4552000         C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ff950220000 - 0x00007ff950228000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ff94ae30000 - 0x00007ff94ae54000         C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ff93c080000 - 0x00007ff93c089000         C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ff950d80000 - 0x00007ff950def000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ff94ae00000 - 0x00007ff94ae2d000         C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ff94e4d0000 - 0x00007ff94e51a000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ff94e250000 - 0x00007ff94e261000         C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ff94a980000 - 0x00007ff94a991000         C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin\verify.dll
0x00007ff93d1a0000 - 0x00007ff93d394000         C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DBGHELP.DLL
0x00007ff93cf30000 - 0x00007ff93cf5a000         C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbgcore.DLL
0x00007ff92e470000 - 0x00007ff92e499000         C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin\java.dll
0x00007ff92e450000 - 0x00007ff92e466000         C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ff94aa80000 - 0x00007ff94aa8a000         C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin\jimage.dll

dbghelp: loaded successfully - version: 4.0.5 - missing functions: none
symbol engine: initialized successfully - sym options: 0x614 - pdb path: .;C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.18362.778_none_e6c6b761130d4fb8;C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\runtime\bin\server

VM Arguments:
java_command: <unknown>
java_class_path (initial): <not set>
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

[Global flags]
     uint G1ConcRefinementThreads                  = 10                                        {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx GCDrainStackTargetSize                   = 64                                        {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 267632960                                 {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 4282127360                                {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ReservedCodeCacheSize                    = 251658240                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
     bool SegmentedCodeCache                       = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedClassPointers               = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedOops                        = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseG1GC                                  = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation        = false                                  {pd product} {ergonomic}

Logging:
Log output configuration:
 #0: stdout all=warning uptime,level,tags
 #1: stderr all=off uptime,level,tags

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\Tim\jdk-13.0.2
PATH=...
USERNAME=Tim
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 23 Model 8 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 18362 (10.0.18362.778)

CPU:total 12 (initial active 12)

Memory: 4k page, system-wide physical 16335M (7401M free)
TotalPageFile size 38863M (AvailPageFile size 26823M)
current process WorkingSet (physical memory assigned to process): 8M, peak: 8M
current process commit charge ("private bytes"): 3M, peak: 3M

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-LTS) for windows-amd64 JRE (11.0.1+13-LTS), built on Oct  6 2018 13:20:16 by "mach5one" with MS VC++ 15.5 (VS2017)

END.
```

Comment: Consider switching out the built in jdk for one that works? Looks like a jvm bug to me.